# IF statement to change a userType to 'admin'

Tags: php, sql, if-statement

In an sql table there are 3 fields:

- userID
- userType
- username

I am doing some admin functionality and  am having trouble with the syntax whereby i'm wanting to create a  so that when it is clicked on, it will run an IF statement to check whether a user's userType is either a jobseeker or an employer and if so, change their userType to admin.

Here is the code so far (I haven't got very far..)

```
<div id="makeAdmin">
    <?php
    $sQuery = 'SELECT userID, userType FROM user';

       $result = mysql_query($sQuery);

    //IF STATEMENT T CHANGE USER TO ADMIN
       if ($userType == "jobseeker" || "employer") {

         //CHANGE userType to 'admin'
         //Call the function inside a button
        }
 ?>
 </div>
```

Does anyone know how to change the userType to 'admin'? All help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can't call a PHP function "inside a button". What you'd want to do is to show the button only to jobseeker and employers, then perform an Ajax call to a PHP script when this button is clicked.

Comment: Thank you Nabab, The button was going to have jQuery applied to it to listen for a click function which would then send the AJAX data.

Comment: Then you send the userId to your PHP script called through AJAX and do `UPDATE user SET userType = 'admin' WHERE userID = %u and ( userType LIKE 'jobseeker' OR userType LIKE 'employer' )`

Answer (score 2):

Try somthing like this :

```
<div id="makeAdmin">
<?php
$sQuery = mysql_query('SELECT userID, userType FROM user');
$result = mysql_fetch_object($sQuery);

//IF STATEMENT T CHANGE USER TO ADMIN
   if ($result->userType == "jobseeker" || $result->userType == "employer") {

     //CHANGE userType to 'admin'
     //Call the function inside a button
    }
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

isn't your if condition should be

`if (($result->userType == "jobseeker") || ($result->userType == "employer"))`